# The Three.js object cannot be embeded in the CSS3DObject

Tags: css, three.js, embed, invisible

I'm trying to get a clone of a raycasted object, and move the clone of the selected object in a `<div>`. The `raycaster` works just fine, but the `CSS3DObject` instance (the cloned 3d Object) is not shown in the scene. I have made another renderer (namely a `CSS3DRenderer`), in addition to the current `WebGLRenderer`, and basically my css3d code consists of this:

```
  cssRenderer = new CSS3DRenderer();
  cssRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  cssRenderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
  cssRenderer.domElement.style.top = 0;
  cssScene = new THREE.Scene();
  document.body.appendChild(cssRenderer.domElement);
```

...

```
  thumbnail = document.querySelector('.thumbnail');
  thumbObject = new CSS3DObject(thumbnail);
```

....

```
  targetClone = target.clone();
  thumbObject.position.copy(targetClone.position);
  cssScene.add(thumbObject);
```

and my render loop code, pertaining to this, is:

```
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
  renderer.render(scene, camera); // WebGLRenderer
  cssRenderer.render(cssScene, camera); //CSS3DRenderer
```

My intention is to embed the cloned object (`targetClone`) in the `CSS3DObject` (`thumbObject`, which in actuality is an HTML element). The console shows no error, and I cannot see any reaction to this code whatsoever (except that the `div` travels to the center of model!) No matter if I select the `div` through traversing the DOM or making a fresh element by means of `createElement`, nothing is being embedded in the div. I suspect that everything is behind the scene(s). Any ideas how can I achieve this, and where I'm doing it wrong?